# calling functions and click animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one rectangle, 2 functions that animates different this rectangle at different window widths, and  im calling the functions with a click. it Must work when screen resizes as well.

Problems:

1- it seems like when I load one function then the other cant work, only the first.

2- It doesn't work on the first click.

3- I have to write the same code for when the document is ready and when the document resize.

How can I fix this 3 points. thx. code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function lateralMove() {
        $(".rectangle-1").off("click").click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                left: "+=50"
            }, 500);
        })
    }

    function horizontalMove() {
        $(".rectangle-1").off("click").click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: "+=50"
            }, 500);
        })
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        screenWidth = $(this).width()
    })

    $(".rectangle-1").click(function () {
        if (screenWidth > 300) {
            lateralMove()
        } else if (screenWidth <= 300) {
            horizontalMove()
        }
    })

    screenWidth = $(window).width()
    if (screenWidth > 300) {
        blackMove()
    } else if (screenWidth <= 300) {
        horizontalMove()
    }

})
```

```css
.rectangle-1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;  
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="rectangle-1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a matter of cleaning up your code (you had a function call to a function called blackMove() that was undefined) and you also needed to wrap the "assign movement" portion of your code in a function and call it on document ready and on window resize.

Here's the code pen: 
http://codepen.io/nhmaggiej/full/azXgqw/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function verticalMove() {

    $(".rectangle-1").off("click").click(function () {

        $(this).animate({
            left: "+=50"
        }, 500);
    })
}

function horizontalMove() {

    $(".rectangle-1").off("click").click(function () {

        $(this).animate({
            top: "+=50"
        }, 500);
    })
}




function assignMovement() {
    screenWidth = $(this).width()
    if (screenWidth > 600) {

        verticalMove()
    } else if (screenWidth <= 600) {

        horizontalMove()
    }

};

$(window).resize(function () {
    assignMovement();
})

assignMovement();
```

});

Comment: Thx mate, everyone pretty much nailed it but  ill give you the best answer because you wrote all the code.

Answer (score 1):

just cal a different function depending n a screen width:

```
function do_mobile(){
 //do
}
function do_desktop(){
 //do
}
$(".rectangle-1").on("click", function(){  
     if( $(window).width() > 300 ){
         do_desktop();
     }
     else{
         do_mobile();
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will move the square onload, onresize and when the square is clicked.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj4ecxhf/)

```
function lateralMove(elementX) {
    elementX.animate({
        left: "+=50"
    }, 500);
}

function horizontalMove(elementX) {
    elementX.animate({
        top: "+=50"
    }, 500);
}

function elementMove() {
    screenWidth = $(window).width();
    elementX = $(".rectangle-1");

    if (screenWidth > 300) {
        lateralMove(elementX);
    } else if (screenWidth <= 300) {
        horizontalMove(elementX);
    }
}

//move on resize
//Use a Timeout to ensure that the resize event is only fired once per change.
$(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(this.id);
    this.id = setTimeout(elementMove, 500);
});

//move on click
$(".rectangle-1").click(function () {
    elementMove();
})

//move on load
elementMove();
```